# How efficient is HDF5 for data retrieval as opposed to data storage?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hdf5, bigdata

I would like to dump a keyed 500GB table into HDF5, and then then retrieve rows matching specific keys.

For an HDF5 file, items like all the data access uses an integer "row" number, so seems like I would have to implement a 'key to row number map" outside of HDF5.

Isn't retrieval more efficient with a distributed system like Hadoop or Spark which uses HDFS? Should I be using a distributed system to implement the map/hashfunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes using HDFS can be more efficient
But to make it more efficient best case can be by using Hive over HDFS because Map reduce do not provide any default way to separate data by key. If you want to separate data by key you need to code for it.

But in case of Hive you can query data more efficiently because hive gives you lots of inbuilt queries commands like ex--> separate by key, by value etc.
Since Hive is using Sql queries it is more easy to use also.

For more details about different ways in which you can query HDFS refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: In what sense are we using mapreduce instead of just of accessing key-value pairs? Why would HIVE be more efficient than HDF5?

Answer (score 1):

HDFS will keep the data in blocks and then, depending on the data format, a query will read blocks at a time and parse the records. HDFS by itself won't provide the by-key-lookup.

Take a look at HBase. It will store the data in HDFS and give you a key -> value interface to look up rows: https://hbase.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me some sense how poorly HDF5 would perform in this situation? If there's decent indexing, this is just a huge dictionary, right?